# Incompatible Types Error - how to fix that?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on one Android Studio project which has some errors in java code.
As stated in the question I get the **Incompatible Types Error.** the error text as follows.

> Incompatible Types Error:
>
> Required :com.tutorial.air.model.json.Object
>
> Found :Java.util.concurrent.Executer

Here I've attached the resposible Java method.

```
public <S extends SyncManager> S createSyncManager(Class<S> cls, Object obj) {
        if (obj != null) {
            try {
                Class cls2 = obj.getClass();
                if (obj instanceof RealmModel) {
                    cls2 = Util.getOriginalModelClass(((RealmModel) obj).getClass());
                }
                return (SyncManager) cls.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[]{Executor.class, SessionManager.class, cls2}).newInstance(new Object[]{this.mExecutor, this, obj});
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return (SyncManager) cls.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[]{Executor.class, SessionManager.class}).newInstance(new Object[]{this.mExecutor, this});
    }
```

The error lies on two lines:

> return (SyncManager) cls.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[]{Executor.class, SessionManager.class, cls2}).newInstance(new Object[]{**this.mExecutor, this,** obj});

and

> return (SyncManager) cls.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[]{Executor.class, SessionManager.class}).newInstance(new Object[]{**this.mExecutor, this**});

Highlighted words have issue.

Let me know if need anything else to investigate. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import com.tutorial.air.Application;
import com.tutorial.air.model.json.AuthCredential;
import com.tutorial.air.model.json.AuthCredential.Type;
import com.tutorial.air.model.json.MigrateRequest;
import com.tutorial.air.model.json.Object;
import com.tutorial.air.model.json.RegisterRequest;
import com.tutorial.air.model.json.Token;
import com.tutorial.air.model.realm.User;
import com.tutorial.air.network.AuthService;
import com.tutorial.air.network.RestClient;
import com.tutorial.air.utils.Date;
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. This `new Object` does not refer to `java.lang.Object`, thus you can't put "anything" into an array of that type.

Comment: This error means either "this.mExecutor, this" either one of this is not "com.tutorial.air.model.json.Object" this type. Can you add the error shown in logs?

Comment: Please upload `import` lines of your source code.

Comment: @Toris Done adding

Comment: The below answer is correct. To elaborate further: You should really never name a Class `Object` as `java.lang.Object` is the Parent-Class of all Classes and this really causes confusion. The newInstance function expects `java.lang.Object[]` but you are passing `com.tutorial.air.model.json.Object[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear this line.

> ```
> import com.tutorial.air.model.json.Object;
> ```

If you are using `Object` as `com.tutorial.air.model.json.Object`, it shuold be changed to `com.tutorial.air.model.json.Object`, then.

`Object` means `java.lang.Object` by default.

Or

keep current imports and use `java.lang.Object` for error lines.

Comment: This is wrong, the newInstance method actually expects something like `com.tutorial.air.model.json.Object` (even though that is a really bad name for a class). The problem seems to be the arguments to the newInstance method don't match the constructor

Comment: @JensV Use `java.lang.Object` or `com.tutorial.air.model.json.Object` for other one. Basically, it's later one though.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't catch that the Object[] array also had the wrong type.

Comment: Well `com.tutorial.air.model.json.Object` class has nothing in it. So I try `java.lang.Object` now.